# Best approach for migrating connection strings to windows Auth

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, connection-string

We have 8 IIS machines and 2 SQL Server 2008 machines running several aspnet apps. We have desktop apps that connect to the DBs as well. We want to get rid of credentials stored in config files and change the con strings to use windows auth. What would be the best approach to this besides creating a login for each machine. Domain groups, or roles etc.

Thanks